# RxAndroid - Return an arraylist from flatMap

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I just started delving into RxJava/RxAndroid in combination with Retrofit. I love the power RxAndroid provides, but I am stuck at a particular place and can't seem to figure out a solution. I basically have an API which takes an user and gets info about that user from the API, while this works great what I would like to do is instead of returning info of each user separately return an arraylist of userinfo.

```
 Observable.from(interestingUsers)  //3 users declared statically for test
              .flatMap(user -> gitHubService.getUserData(user))
              .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
              .subscribe(gitHubUser -> Log.e("Log", "User data returned : " + gitHubUser.getName()));
```

The above code just logs individual users thrice, what I would rather want is a list of the 3 users being returned as a single result.

I know this could be something trivial and I just can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Observable.toList`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#toList()) transforms an `Observable<T>` to `Observable<List<T>>`:

```
Observable.from(interestingUsers)
    .flatMap(user -> gitHubService.getUserData(user))
    .toList()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(users -> {
        for (final User user : users) {
            Log.e("Log", "User data returned : " + user.getName())
        }
    });
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for ! Thanks a ton. Will accept the answer as soon as SO lets me

Comment: This is not working unless all the Observables are completed. We need to make sure of that